# Linq query referencing objects and a string array

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am having some trouble in converting the following code to use LINQ.

```
int occurs = 0;
foreach (string j in items)
{
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(j))
            {
                WorkflowModule tempWM = new WorkflowModule(j);
                if (tempWM.StateID == item.StateID)
                {
                    occurs++;
                }
            }
        }
        return occurs;
```

So far, I have:-

```
var lstItems = (from lstItem in items
                        where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lstItem)
                        let objWorkflowModule = new WorkflowModule(lstItem)
                        select new
                        {
                            tempWM = objWorkflowModule.StateID
                        }).Where(item.StateID == tempWM));

        return lstItems.Count();
```

but intellisense is not liking the line '.Where(item.StateID == tempWM))'

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

When you use the method syntax, you need to use a lambda on the `Where` operator:

```
...
}).Where(x => x.tempWM == item.StateID));
```

In other words, you need to "declare" the variable `x` which holds the result of the previous part of the query.

Comment: I think they actually want `Where(t => t.tempWM == item.StateID)` because item seems to be a variable defined outside the original code.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like item is initialized anywhere in your statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do this

```
var lstItems = from lstItem in items
               where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lstItem)
               let objWorkflowModule = new WorkflowModule(lstItem)
               select objWorkflowModule.StateID;

return lstItems.Count(t=> t == item.StateID);
```

I'm assuming item is a variable defined outside of the original code you submitted.  Basically you don't need to create the anonymous class in the query and you can put the predicate in you're `Where` into `Count` instead.  But as others have said the main issue is that you need to express your predicate as a lambda.